# Service doesn't respond to form submitting value

Tags: angular, typescript, service

This is my read.html where the form is filled and submitted.

```
  <form class="mt-3 text-center" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
              <div class="text-center">
                <input type="text" name="barcode" class="form-control text-center mt-2" [(ngModel)]="barcode" placeholder="Barcode">
              </div>
            </form>
```

This is my read.ts where after the form being submitted calls a service and returns the information.

```
 constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.codEspec = params['CodEspec'];
        this.DiaHoraEspecs = params['DiaHoraEspecs'];
    });
     }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit(){      
    console.log(this.barcode,this.codEspec,this.DiaHoraEspecs );
    this.ticketlineservice.CheckTicket(this.barcode, this.codEspec, this.DiaHoraEspecs).subscribe(reads => {
      this.reads = reads[0].Tickets;
      console.log(reads);
  });
}
```

The function of the service I'm calling. The other two params(codEspec and DiaHoraEspecs) come from a previous url.

```
 CheckTicket(barcode, codEspec, diaHoraEspec):Observable<Ticket[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Ticket[]>(`${this.url_node_tickets}${this.barcode}${this.codEspec}${this.diaHoraEspec}`, httpOptions);
  }
```

**Problem:** in the console log all the values appear and are correct, but in the url the barcode doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CheckTicket(barcode, codEspec, diaHoraEspec):Observable<Ticket[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Ticket[]>(`${this.url_node_tickets}${this.barcode}${this.codEspec}${this.diaHoraEspec}`, httpOptions);
  }
```

`${this.barcode}${this.codEspec}${this.diaHoraEspec}`

I think you need to remove `this` (class reference) on those and use the parameters of the function?
`${barcode}${codEspec}${diaHoraEspec}`

Comment: Removing the `this` the url stays the same and doesn't change the params.

Comment: is this a proper angular class service, `this` should refer to the class, not the function.